# How cast string to voption struct?

Tags: f#

i have simple struct

```
[<Struct>]
type Phone = private Phone of string
```

and i need cast to Phone voption

```
let toVOption (phone: string) : Phone voption = phone |> ValueOption.toObj
```

end i see error

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a 'string -> Phone voption' but given a ''a voption -> 'a' The type 'string' does not match the type ''a voption'
```

how correct cast string to Phone voption?

Comment: By the way, what you're trying to do is not *casting* from `string` to `Phone voption` but *wrapping* a string into a `Phone voption`. So you end up with a value option holding a `Phone` inside, and that `Phone` holding a `string` inside. Hope that makes sense. `ValueOption.toObj` is used to unwrap a `ValueOption`, where `ValueNone` is mapped to `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the `string` in a `Phone`, and then wrap the `Phone` in a `ValueOption`:

```
let toVOption (phone: string) : Phone voption = phone |> Phone |> ValueSome
```